# Postfix with opendkim: missing id's

Tags: email, postfix, opendkim

I'm setting up a high performance mailserver using multi-instance postfix with TLS and opendkim. This machine is only for sending.

All seems to be well, except that when submitting lots of messages the normal flow of adding a signature, delivering and removing from the queue changes: first I see long sequences of dkim signatures being added, and only then the delivery starts.

Looking like this:

```
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: C6453C0000996: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: C8C88C0000997: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: C9CF4C000099A: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: CADDBC000099B: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: CE31DC0017335: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D0509C000099C: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D35F6C0017326: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D45C9C000099D: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D6C41801BAD26: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D7DDBC0017330: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
May 22 05:00:42 bartok opendkim[1637]: D9D7DC000099E: DKIM-Signature field added (s=k1, d=bounced.nl)
```

etc.

This seems to be holding back delivery; is this normal?

But the main question I have is that lot of these id's (like C6453C0000996) never show up in the logs again; so no information about delivering (or bouncing).

Does this mean these emails are 'gone' somehow? Should they not show up in the logs in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: this wasn't an issue with postfix or opendkim, but with log messages being suppressed by systemd-journal. Editing the ratelimits in /etc/systemd/journald.conf solved it.